# Facebook chat plugin not loaded give me error in console

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook

See I copy the code from facebook and paste in my HTML page

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
<div class="fb-customerchat"
 page_id="My-page-id">
</div>
```

And i get error in my console is:

**The CustomerChat plugin is no longer part of the main Facebook SDK.
To continue using it please use the correct SDK URL,
meaning replace sdk.js with sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js.
For more details see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/sdk**

I am tried to replace with sdk.js but it's not working. Please help me out here.

Comment: There’s a bug report about this issue here, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/194139881470565/, but the responses don’t seem to be that helpful. // Are you embedding the “standard” SDK on that same site as well? In that case, I think the code they provide for loading the two collides, because in _both_ the specify the script element id as `facebook-jssdk`. Try and change that to something else - the embedder script checks for that id before it loads the script, so that it doesn’t load it more than once, but with two different SDKs that obviously would cause a problem.

Comment: Thanks, @misorude this information is useful to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

check here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/sdk

> https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js requests
>   a version of the Facebook Javascript SDK that includes the Customer
>   Chat SDK. With this URL, you will still be able to access all of the
>   Facebook Javascript SDK plus all features of the Customer Chat SDK.

you just need to add 1 sdk (not both fb sdk + chat)